# (R) IF statement: stop & warn if FALSE else continue

Tags: r, unit-testing

I'm making a function and before it does any of the hard stuff I need it to check that all the column names listed in the 'samples' dataset are also present in the 'grids' dataset (the function maps one onto the other).

```
all(names(samples[expvar]) %in% names(grids))
```

This does that: the code within all() asks if all the names in the list ('expvar') of columns in 'samples' are also names in 'grids'. The output for a correct `length=3`, `expvar` would be `TRUE TRUE TRUE`. 'all' asks if all are TRUE, so the output here is TRUE. I want to make an IF statement along the lines of:

```
if(all(names(samples[expvar]) %in% names(grids)) = FALSE) {stop("Not all expvar column names found as column names in grids")}
```

No else needed, it'll just carry on. The problem is that the '= FALSE' is redundant because all() is a logically evaluable statement... is there a "carry on" function, e.g.

```
if(all(etc)) CARRYON else {stop("warning")}
```

Or, can anyone think of a way I can restructure this to make it work?

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow since it's about programming and not statistics. Also, you should use the code highlighting syntax to make this post more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would code it:

```
if(!all(...))
    stop(...)
... rest of program ...
```

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the function `stopifnot`.

However you don't need to implement it as

```
if (okay) {
  # do stuff
} else {
  stop()
}
```

which is what you have. Instead you can do

```
if (!okay) {
  stop()
}
# do stuff
```

since the lines will execute in sequential order. But, again, it might be more readable to use `stopifnot`, as in:

```
stopifnot(okay)
# do stuff
```

Comment: thanks, didn't know about stopifnot, and (!okay) is the kind of obvious logic that was eluding my addled brain. Cheers!